# Microsoft SQL Server, dequeue message with specific priority

Tags: sql-server, database, message-queue, priority-queue

I am trying to retrieve a message from the queue using:

```
RECEIVE TOP (1) CAST(message_body AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM Queue
```

is there any why that I can add a condition to retrieve the message with just High priority and if I don't have any high priority message I retrieve nothing